I cannot connect to the Internet (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)
My computer won't connect to the Internet.
I installed Ubuntu on a PC with Windows 10. I replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu during the installation. When I was on Windows 10, the internet still worked as usual, but when I installed Ubuntu, it couldn't connect to the Internet.
I have tried hotspots on my phone, changing the network settings, using the terminal to change network settings, changing nameserver, but it still wouldn't work.
Connection on Windows 10 was wireless.
EDIT:
Output of lspci:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family NEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:12.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) 00:16.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

00:10.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) 00:10.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)

00:10.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Fanily Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SNBus Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE node, ports 4-5) (rev 05) 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 0021 ID 808710024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub Bus 001 Device 0031 ID 093a12516 Pixart Imaging, Inc. USB OPTICAL MOUSE

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 002: ID 808710024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 256010001 SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD

Bus 002 Device 004: ID @bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

Please ignore potentional misspellings, as I used Google Lens to scan the outputs.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include the brand/model of your computer? It would also be helpful to see the terminal output of lspci and lsusb, as these will show specific details about your hardware. With this, it may be possible to offer a specific solution

UPDATE: Turns out it was just some windows process still running in the background. Unplugging and replugging resolves my problem. (7/12/2024)
—————
Old answer:
To provide more details on how I tried to solve it.
I tried to connect an iPhone to my computer using USB tethering, hoping to at least get a ethernet/wired connection. Then, I turned it on, and it just suddenly connected to the internet. I'm not sure if it was the fault of the USB or just a sudden tempoary problem that was solved.
Thanks so much for all the help!
(self-answer)

it seems the Driver shows in lsusb, could share any SS, or error when you try to connect Internet, then it easy to identify the problem,
if the WIfi option not able to see in settings, then try this cmd
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
best of luck!

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.
